# How can I override DeviseController#find_message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, internationalization

I need to do I18n translation by-hand in my views to support translating to multiple languages side-by-side, but Devise translates it's flash messages internally based on the current locale, setting the resulting string in `flash`.

I need it to just add the I18n key and options to `flash` so that i can do something like

```
zh = t(key, locale: 'zh-CN')
en = t(key, locale: 'en')
```

It looks like the code in question is [`DeviseController#find_message`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v4.3.0/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L180), but I can't figure out how to override / monkey-patch that... I've tried

```
DeviseController.class_eval do
  # Get message for given
  def find_message(kind, options = {})
    options[:scope] ||= translation_scope
    options[:default] = Array(options[:default]).unshift(kind.to_sym)
    options[:resource_name] = resource_name
    options = devise_i18n_options(options)

    # return the i18n key itself to facilitate multiple translations
    # I18n.t("#{options[:resource_name]}.#{kind}", options)
    {key: "#{options[:resource_name]}.#{kind}", options: options}
  end
end
```

in `config/initializers/devise.rb`, but it seems to have no effect.

How can override or patch this behavior?

I'm using Devise 4.3.0 (most recent at time of writing) and Rails 5.1.1, by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; for anyone else looking: you want to override `Devise::FailureApp#i18n_message`.

This worked:

```
Devise::FailureApp.class_eval do
  protected
    def i18n_message(default = nil)
      message = warden_message || default || :unauthenticated

      if message.is_a?(Symbol)
        options = {}
        options[:resource_name] = scope
        options[:scope] = "devise.failure"
        options[:default] = [message]
        auth_keys = scope_class.authentication_keys
        keys = (auth_keys.respond_to?(:keys) ? auth_keys.keys : auth_keys).map { |key| scope_class.human_attribute_name(key) }
        options[:authentication_keys] = keys.join(I18n.translate(:"support.array.words_connector"))
        options = i18n_options(options)

        # I18n.t(:"#{scope}.#{message}", options)
        {key: :"#{scope}.#{message}", options: options}
      else
        message.to_s
      end
    end
end
```